# Incorrect POS Tagging with NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to implement chunking using NLTK. But, I am having problems while assigning POS Tags to the words. It gives a different output when the data is passed as it is in a file and the tagging is wrong in many cases. When I convert the text to lowercase, it correctly assigns the tags. But the chunking is not correct.

**My Code**

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

sample_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")

words = nltk.word_tokenize(sample_text.lower()) # it makes correct pos tags in this case
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sample_text) # it does not make correct pos tags in this case

tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
print(tagged)
chunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<NNP>+<NN>?}"""
chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged) 
for subtree in chunked.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'Chunk'):
    print(subtree)
```

**Output when POS Tagging is correct:**

> [('president', 'NN'), ('george', 'NN'), ('w.', 'VBD'), ('bush', 'NN'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('address', 'NN'), ('before', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('joint', 'JJ'), ('session', 'NN'),

and so on....
there are no chunks printed

**Output when POS Tagging is incorrect:**

> [('PRESIDENT', 'NNP'), ('GEORGE', 'NNP'), ('W.', 'NNP'), ('BUSH', 'NNP'), ("'S", 'POS'), ('ADDRESS', 'NNP'), ('BEFORE', 'IN'), ('A', 'NNP'), ('JOINT', 'NNP'),

and so on...
chunks are printed in this case but due to wrong POS tags, the chunks are not correct.

> (Chunk PRESIDENT/NNP GEORGE/NNP W./NNP BUSH/NNP)
> (Chunk ADDRESS/NNP)
> (Chunk A/NNP JOINT/NNP SESSION/NNP)
> (Chunk THE/NNP CONGRESS/NNP ON/NNP THE/NNP STATE/NNP)

why the POS tagging is producing different results when the words are in different cases? I am new to NLTK therefore unable to get the issue. Thanks

**Data file**
The data file used can be found [here](https://github.com/teropa/nlp/blob/master/resources/corpora/state_union/2006-GWBush.txt) in the NLTK library. It is already there in NLTK when you download it in your system. You won't need to import it separately.

Comment: What's in 2006-GWBush.txt? Can you share a small sample in your question for reproduction?

Comment: @DSteman it is already in nltk. I'll share it

Comment: @DSteman I have added the reference to the data file used. Could you please have a look.